# NetLogo Behavior Space doesn't count one of my breeds

Tags: netlogo

I'm working on a model to simulate tick bites in the Netherlands. My code is finished and now I want to use Behavior Space to generate output files. I've got two breeds in my model, 'residents' and 'tourists-2d'. From both breeds, I want to count how many turtles got a tick bite. The residents-breed is working but the tourists-breed isn't. Can anybody help me how to fix this? I think it is because my tourists-breed comes from a list but I don't know how to fix it. Even if I simply use 'count tourists-2d', the output of Behavior Space is 0.

```
globals [ month month-day week week-day tourist-2d-list ]
breed [ residents resident ]
breed [ tourists-2d tourist-2d ]

to setup
  ca
  file-close-all
  reset-ticks

; ---------- Creating tourist-lists -----------
  set tourist-2d-list (list 1 1 2 4 8 17 38 85 188 420 935 2086 4651 10371 18750 18750 10371 4651 2086 935 420 188 85 38 17 8 4 2 1 1)
end

to go
  set month ceiling(ticks / 30)
  set month-day (ticks mod 30)
  set week ceiling(ticks / 7)
  set week-day (ticks mod 7)

; ---------- Set tick dynamics per month ----------

  if month = 13 and month-day = 1 [reset-ticks]

; ---------- Set 2-day tourist dynamics per week ----------

 initialize-tourists-2d

  tick

 remove-tourists
end


to initialize-tourists-2d
    if week-day = 6 [
    if week > 14 and week < 45 [
      create-tourists-2d item (week - 15) tourist-2d-list [set color pink set shape "person" setxy -14 -7 set stay-period 2 set day-counter 0 ]
    ]
  ]
end

to remove-tourists
  ask tourists-2d [set day-counter (day-counter + 1)
    if day-counter = stay-period [die]
  ]
end
```

Additional info to my code, tourist-2d-list is a global and tourists-2d a breed. It would be great if somebody could help me!

Comment: Ignore BehaviorSpace initially. Put a monitor on your interface and try to make it display the information you want. Show us the monitor code.

Comment: Already did that! I used `count tourists-2d` and that is working fine. However, if I use that same code with BehaviorSpace it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please post a minimal working example for such a question.  This would look like the following:

```
globals [tourist-2d-list week-day week]
breed [tourists-2d tourist-2d]

to setup
  set tourist-2d-list (list 1 1 2 4 8 17 38 85 188 420 935 2086 4651 10371 18750 18750 
                            10371 4651 2086 935 420 188 85 38 17 8 4 2 1 1)
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if (ticks > (45 * 7)) [stop]
  set week-day ticks mod 7
  set week (int ticks / 7)
  add-tourists
  tick
end

to add-tourists
if week-day = 6 and week > 14 and week < 45 [
  create-tourists-2d item (week - 15) tourist-2d-list [init-tourist]
  print (count tourists-2d) ;print to debug
]
end

to init-tourist
  ; put initializations here
end
```

As you can see, the count is not zero.

Comment: I added more of my code. When I count tourists-2d with a monitor it is working fine but it seems not to work when using BehaviorSpace.

Comment: Just to chekc the obvious, you are saying that you (i) include `count tourists-2d` in the BehaviorSpace dialoge (ii) run the simulation with "Measure runs at every step" ticked, and (iii) see output for more than 14 weeks but the column for "count tourists-2d" is always zero.  Is that the claim?

Comment: Yes exactly! I get 360 ticks (my model runs for one year) and at every tick the number of tourists-2d is 0.

Comment: @JasmijnKok You must be doing something additional to cause your problem.  To demonstrate that, try the following.  Start NetLogo to begin a new model.  Copy the code I provided above into the `Code` tab.  Create a new experiment as following: change `count turtles` to `count tourists-2d`.  Don't make any other changes.  Run the experiment and save the output to temp.csv.  Examine the output: it is fine.

Comment: I think the problem is caused by the `remove-tourists` procedure? The tourists are removed from the model before they are counted I guess.